# jqGrid data not showing but rows are generating

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

I am working on a MVC application. I have written a jqGrid in my aspx page.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            jQuery("#jqgajax").jqGrid({

                url: 'http://localhost:54136/home/fetchData',
                datatype: "json",
                colNames: ['ProcessName', 'WorkingSet64'],
                colModel: [
                            { name: 'ProcessName', index: 'ProcessName', width: 55 },
                            { name: 'WorkingSet64', index: 'WorkingSet64', width: 90 }
                        ],
                rowNum: 80,
                mtype:'Get',
                width: 700,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                sortname:'id',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                caption: "New API Example"
            });
        });
```

**C# Code at controller:**

```
 var jsonData = new
           {
               total =10,
               page = 10,
               records = 10,
               rows = (
                from p in pu
                select new
                {
                    id = ++counter,
                    cell = new
                    {
                        ProcessName = p.ProcessName.ToString(),
                        WorkingSet64 = p.Memory.ToString()
                    }
                }).ToArray()
           };


            return Json(jsonData,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**The issue it rows are getting generated in the grid, but there is no data in the rows.**
[image]

Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#json_data) wait for `cell` as array of strings. So you should replace the part of the code

```
cell = new
{
    ProcessName = p.ProcessName.ToString(),
    WorkingSet64 = p.Memory.ToString()
}
```

to

```
cell = new [] { p.ProcessName, p.Memory.ToString() }
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked like a charm, But please let me know why it is made like this, in a row I would have only single entity not an array.

Comment: @vaibhav: You should just choose some format of the JSON data and define `jsonReader` option of jqGrid which describe the JSON format. For example if `ProcessName` value is unique you can use `var jsonData = (from p in pu select new { ProcessName = p.ProcessName, WorkingSet64 = p.Memory.ToString() }).ToArray()` inside of the server code. Then JSON will be like `[{"ProcessName": "p1", "WorkingSet64": "123"}, {"ProcessName": "p2", "WorkingSet64":"345"}]`.

Comment: @vaibhav: To read the data you can use `jsonReader: {repeatitems: false, id: "ProcessName", records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }, root: function (obj) { return obj; }, page: function () { return 1; }, total: function () { return 1; }}`. There are many other examples how you can format the data on the server, but you should always use the corresponding `jsonReader` or sometimes additionally `jsonmap` attribute in the `colModel`.